# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type oid: "english"

Tags: postgresql, index, query, postgresql-9.5

While creating an index in Postgres I am getting an error:

> invalid input syntax for type oid: "english"
>
> LINE 1: ...s ON entity_attributes2 USING gist ( (to_tsvector('english',...

The query which I have used to create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX json_fts ON table USING gist ( (to_tsvector('english', abc->>'email_address')));
```

The abc column is of jsonb type and it contains the following data:

```
{
    "account": "10",
    "name": "Scott Theisman",
    "manageremail": "eric.larsen@xxx.com",
    "active": "t",
    "email_address": "scott.theisman@xxx.com",
    "employeeid": "74322509"
}
```

Comment: Does the 'english' text search configuration exist in your database?  You can use the `\dF` command in psql.